# How do vectors and other containers work on the disk?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble finding information regarding this online, likely because I don't know what terms to use.

When I create a vector, array, unordered map, etc. in C++ or any similar language, what happens on the disk? I always imagined that the vector acts as a list of pointers pointing to memory addresses on the disk while the actual vector that I access in code is only the memory address of the list itself; that is to say, my code knows the address of the vector and the vector knows the addresses of its elements scattered randomly on the disk. Is this correct? I do not know where I learned this so that's why I am doubting it. Also, there are likely resources available addressing this question and how other pieces of code operate on the disk. If so, can someone point me to them? Thank you.

Comment: What you're interested is part of **operating systems**. Unless you're computer's processes are using more memory than your computer's physical memory, then you won't be using your storage drive at all, it will instead sit only on memory. Most OS's use "paging" nowadays, so you're right that vectors could be broken up into different parts of the **memory**, and if the OS can't find space for a new allocation that it will use any available storage on your **storage drive** in a similar paging fashion. From the OS's point of view, the storage drive is just a slower form  of memory for a process.

Comment: The OS term for this technique of using the storage device to hold temporary process data is called **caching**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal containers do nothing on disc, they are purely memory constructs.

An array (std::array) is simply a wrapper around a native array type which is a sequence of objects of all the same type.

A vector object will generally directly contain a base pointer and either an end pointer or a size, as well as an allocator (only needed if the allocator has state, it may well be optimized away and not need space in memory).

A std::list will contain head and tail node pointers and again an allocator if it is not optimized away.

Other containers store whatever is needed by the particular pattern used to implement them.

Comment: So does that mean that the vector's base pointer points to the location in memory where its elements start while the vector itself (the base pointer, end pointer/size, and allocator) may be in another portion of the memory? What happens in the extreme circumstance where the vector takes up more space than the memory has?

Comment: @ifonlyihadcake: It won't take up more space. At a certain point, a `push_back` will throw `std::bad_alloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not finding anything because that's simply not how C++ works. Whether it's `vector` or `string`, objects like that live in memory and not on disk.

To create files on disk, you need something like `std::fstream`.